# Полиморфизм в ООП

Tags: ооп, полиморфизм

ООП базируется на трех основных свойствах - наследование, инкапсуляция и полиморфизм. Вопрос в следующем: полиморфизм в ооп - это всегда ad-hoc полиморфизм? Все говорят, что это именно он. Но ad-hoc полиморфизм основам на перегрузке процедур и приведении типов. В некоторых ООП языках отсутствует возможность перегрузки методов и раз это так, то о каком полиморфизме тогда там идет речь?

Почему не сказать, что в ООП применяется полиморфизм подтипов? Ведь класс B наследуемый от класса A является подтипом класса A и может использовать все унаследованные методы, переопределяя и дополняя их. Это же полиморфизм подтипов, или?

Или пойдем от обратного. Если вы опровергаете это, то какой полиморфизм будет в языках где отсутствует перегрузка?

Comment: Думаю, что собственно сам ооп не заморачиваться на такие мелочи. Но если что, Я могу делать полиморфизм на си, где перегрузки и классов нет

Comment: Мне всегда было интересно в вопросах подобного типа......а какая разница как это называется? Ну полиморфизм и полиморфизм. Зачем копать на столько глубоко? Экзамен в межвселенную академию  сдавать?

Comment: нет не сдавать, люблю называть зеленое - зеленым, а синее - синим

Comment: Так называйте так, как вам удобно. Всё равно никто, кроме вас так называть не будет. Т.е. использовать термин будете только вы один среди живых существ. Так что можете назвать это хоть АБЫРВАЛГ %)

Comment: У меня на собесе спросили, какой тип полиморфизма используется в ООП в PHP. Я подумал и сказал - полиморфизм подтипов. Надо мной посмеялись и сказали неверно, это ad-hoc. Ну и после этого ты будешь говорить, что это нужно только мне и я могу назвать это АБЫРВАЛГ %)

Answer (score 1):

В языках выделяют даже (классификация Лука Карделли) **четыре разновидности** полиморфизма:

1. универсальный (параметрический, включения (или подтипов));
2. ad-hoc (перегрузка, приведение типов)

Comment: Ну возьмем PHP. Там нет перегрузки методов, но есть хорошее ООП. Какой полиморфизм используется там? Получается первый, универсальный, включения (подтипов)?

Comment: Полиморфизм на PHP – это поддержка нескольких реализаций на основе одного общего интерфейса. Почитайте https://it-black.ru/polimorfizm-klassov-v-php/